# How can I print a plot in matplotlib either from the plot window or with a command?

Tags: python, matplotlib

is there a way to print a plot from matplotlib,either with a command or from the plot window itself ? I know i could save it and then print,but I am looking for something more automated.Thanks.

Comment: Print as in sending to a printer? I don't know of any simple interface - it's all complex platform-specific stuff. A search turned up this page on how to print from Python in Windows: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could save the figure as a pdf, then use `subprocess` to print the pdf. On *nix, `lpr` could be used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import shlex

n=20
x=np.linspace(0,np.pi,n)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
fname='/tmp/test.pdf'
plt.savefig(fname)
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('lpr {f}'.format(f=fname)))
```

Comment: Neat. Probably define `fname` before you pass it to `savefig`, though.

Comment: To get this working in Windows I am using,I just replaced the last line with this: win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", '/tmp/test.pdf', None, ".", 0)

Answer (score 1):

From the plot window itself, there is a "save" toggle button, in the shape of a disk on the right side of the row of buttons.

From the command line or script, you can use:

```
    pylab.savefig("directory/filename.pdf")
```

Look here for some of the details:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#plotting-howto